# Paginación de cursor en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un pequeño problema con Laravel 5.4 y ese problema se basa en la paginacion de resultados en un api-rest el cual consumo desde una app de android resulta lo siguiente:

```
[ 0 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0]
imaginen que cada grupo de corchetes es una página
si llamas pag=1 devuelve el primer grupo
si llamas pag=2 devuelve el segundo grupo
(Recordemos que los 0 son fotos ordenadas por creación)
si alguien inserta una nueva foto pasa esto
0 [ 0 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0]
Ese 0 debe entrar en el primer grupo, y al entrar corre los demás 0
[ 0  1  1 ] [ 1  1  1] [1]
Ahora en pag=2 hay un elemento que pertenecía a pag=1
si estas mostrando las fotos usando ajax entonces tendras elementos duplicados
```

El problema es ese en esa pequeña explicación entonces lo que queremos es adaptar o encontrar algun paquete de paginacion en tiempo real algo asi como [esto](https://www.sitepoint.com/paginating-real-time-data-cursor-based-pagination/) en ese tutorial explica como hacer la paginacion de cursor en este caso es para php puro y no esta hecha para Laravel
tambien e visto que aca esta implementada en [fractal.thephpleague](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/pagination/#using-cursors)

Si alguno puede ayudarme con un ejemplo de como solucionar este problema se lo agradecería.

Comment: A mí no me queda muy claro cuál es el problema, ¿aparecen elementos duplicados que no deberían aparecer?

Comment: Si por ejemplo si en un resultado de la paginacion que es usada en ajax hay 10 elementos resulta que se divide de acuerdo a la limitacion de la paginacion en 2 paginas resultados de 5 cada uno pero al momento de este usuario ir a la segunda pagina este resultado se duplica ya que un usuario agrego un nuevo elemento para ser esto en total de 11 en vez de 10 elementos es por eso esta explicacio si alguien inserta una nueva foto pasa esto
0 [ 0 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0]

Answer (score 0):

Para que no se te actualice la paginación debes obtener la fecha de momento  actual y poner una clausula where donde la fecha de creacion sea menor que ahora(hasta aquí el resultado no deberia cambiar) y envias la fecha actual a la vista. 
Cuando cargues las paginas dinamicas envias la fecha en la consulta para que la query solo pagine los elementos creados antes de esa fecha. Asi te aseguras que en la paginacion no aparezcan datos repetidos incluso si se crearon datos despues de hacer la primera paginación.